# MySQL - Update column value based on joined table column value

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I've been reading through SO and other sites, and have followed a few examples; however, my SQL statments is still not performing as required.

I have two tables

---

```
          parts
============================
pmkParts    fnkManufacturer
----------------------------
   0          Penn-Union
   1          Schneider
   2         Telemecanique
```

and

```
         manufacturer   
===============================
Manufacturer    pmkManufacturer
-------------------------------
 Penn-Union          45
 Schneider           56
Telemecanique        12
```

---

I want to change the parts table into

```
          parts
============================
pmkParts    fnkManufacturer
----------------------------
   0             45
   1             56
   2             12
```

Here is the SQL statement I tried.

```
Update parts
SET parts.fnkManufacturer = (
   SELECT manufacturer.pmkManufacturer
   FROM manufacturer
   WHERE manufacturer.pmkManufacturer = parts.fnkManufacturer
   )
```

That is changing the correct column, but it is filling it with 'NULLS' rather than the foreign key (manufacturer). I think there should be a join somewhere in there, but I'm not sure where.

Any tips?

### ----------

### EDIT: Answer:

Here is the SQL statement that worked. Thanks MarcB for the help.

```
Update parts
SET parts.fnkManufacturer = (
   SELECT manufacturer.pmkManufacturer
   FROM manufacturer
   WHERE manufacturer.Manufacturer= parts.fnkManufacturer
   )
```

Comment: what types are those fields? You can't take a string field/fk and update it to an integer still pointing at the same foreign field.

Comment: @MarcB fnkManufacturer is a varchar(50)

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `where man.manufacturer = parts.fnkmanufac`? you're comparing the wrong fields, so nothing matches, and you get a null/empty result from the subselect.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB.. That was a simple solution. My SQL statement worked once I changed that line.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query like below using a update join query. Again, you are joining on the wrong column, you actually should be joining to `manufacturer.Manufacturer` column rather.

```
Update parts p
JOIN manufacturer m ON m.Manufacturer = p.fnkManufacturer
SET p.fnkManufacturer = m.pmkManufacturer;
```

Comment: Thanks. I never actually tried your SQL statement, but your comment was correct. I was comparing the wrong columns, and once I fixed that it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pmkManufacturer` looks like `int` so it is better to add new int field to `parts`, update it and then remove old column. Something like this.

```
alter table dbo.parts add pmkManufacturer int
update dbo.parts 
    set pmkManufacturer = m.pmkManufacturer 
from dbo.parts p
     inner join dbo.Manufacturer m on p.fnkManufacturer = m.manufacturer
```

Comment: Thanks for the option. I have found a solution for the moment, but you definitely have a point.. I will probably have to do this same sort of query in the coming weeks and will look back on this then.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, you could use INNER JOIN, I for example :

```
update parts p
inner join manufacturer m on
    p.pmkManufacturer = m.Manufacturer
set p.pmkManufacturer = m.pmkManufacturer
```

Howerver, in your case, if I was wrong, you want to update `pmkManufacturer` while `pmkManufacturer` is actually the condition `ON` for INNER JOIN so I'm not sure that it'okay for request. If not, it isn't also difficult, you could add a new column : `pmk_bis_manufacturer` and set the value into this column, then delete the old column `pmkManufacturer` and change the name of new column if nescessary.

---

> One tip for you : the name of columns database, I prefer setting :
>   `pmk_manufacturer` instead of `pmkManufacturer` because capital letter in the name
>   could make one problem in the futur. For example : for ORM Doctrine,
>   it isn't good :D